# Unable to insert the virtual optical disk

Tags: virtualbox

Unable to solve this error can anyone help me?

> Unable to insert the virtual optical disk C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxGuestAdditions.iso into the machine ubuntu.
>
> Could not mount the media/drive 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso' (VERR_PDM_MEDIA_LOCKED).
>
> Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
>
> Component: ConsoleWrap
>
> Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
>
> Callee: IMachine {85632c68-b5bb-4316-a900-5eb28d3413df}

Comment: Please provide the applicable log generated by VirtualBox

Answer (score 0):

Shutdown all Open virtual machines, if any VM is in saved state then start it and shut it down. Then go to **File** > **Virtual Media Manager**, and if you find VBoxGuestAdditions.iso among them with check mark, uncheck it. Reboot the VM to check if the problem is solved.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In optical disks I have VBoxGuestAdditions.iso but there is no check box to that

Comment: Then remove it from there

Answer (score -1):

Try to manually mount the virtual CD/DVD drive. This can often help many systems don't mount CDs automatically anymore.

Comment: There's no CD in the (virtual) drive - VirtualBox is erroring out when inserting it. It's a problem on the host, not in the guest.